# delay until function in azure logic apps throwing error

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to add a minute  delay to the "delay until" action by getting the utcnow timestamp, adding a minute and converting into the time format that the "delay until" expects (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-delay#add-the-delay-until-action)

None of the following works and throw the error below, what am i missing here, and is there a way where we can test these function independently without logic apps ?

```
 
1) @addMinutes(utcNow('o'),1,'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ')
2) @addMinutes(utcNow('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ'),1,'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ')
3) @addMinutes(utcNow(),1,'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ')

Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Delay_until' inputs at line '1' and column '2265': 'The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.'.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use this expression:

```
addMinutes(utcNow(),1)
```

I did a test, it seems to be no problem:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Frank, is there a way to test these without using the logic apps ?

Comment: As far as I know, there seems to be no other way.

Comment: thank you , hope MS comes up with something, it will definitely increase the productivity !!!